# When to use the related link relation

Tags: http, iana

The IANA registry contains a official link relation type of "related"

> related: Identifies a related resource.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml

I have also read the referenced [RFC4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.7.2).

> The value "related" signifies that the IRI in the value of the
> href attribute identifies a resource related to the resource
> described by the containing element.  For example, the feed for a
> site that discusses the performance of the search engine at
> "http://search.example.com" might contain, as a child of
> atom:feed:
>
> `<link rel="related" href="http://search.example.com/"/>`
>
> An identical link might appear as a child of any atom:entry whose
> content contains a discussion of that same search engine.

But that only seemed  more confusing to me. Aren't all links related? After all rel = relation.

Can anyone try to clarify this and give valid use cases for rel="related"? Is it just a catch all relation type?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a generic “this link is related to this entry” link relation.

The `related` link relation serves three use cases:

1. Link an entry to a related entry from the same publisher. Some content management systems can keyword-match entry archives and find related/suggested/recommended entries.
2. Link to a related external document. E.g. an entry discussing Facebook’s privacy policy could link to it and a Facebook blog post announcing a policy change. (You can include multiple links with the same relation.) This use cases is intended to enable link-clustering use cases. E.g. grouping entries discussing the same thing/link from different feeds, or rank a  “hot topic” at the top of the feed list (like the [Fever feed reader](https://feedafever.com/) did).
3. Blogs doing reading-list/daily-digests/link-curations/etc. can link to all the external documents they recommend.

The two last use cases are expressions of the [Semantic Web](https://twobithistory.org/2018/05/27/semantic-web.html). This was one of the ways we were supposed to get personalized set of trending topics/links/things from our feed subscription. Twitter and Google Now is the global arbitrators of this today.

However, this link relation can also be used by feed readers to display a list of related links from the publisher. The `link:title` attribute can set the link title to present them to people.